# Как изменить при наведении текст формы?

Tags: html, css

[image: вот картинка с формой]

как изменить, видимо плейсхолдер, при наведении. был инпут с плейхолдером "Name", а при наведении нужно сделать слово ТЕКСТ со своими стилями

Comment: Добавьте код и опишите как конкретно его нужно изменить (текст, размер, цвет)

Comment: @CbIPoK2513 я не особо понимаю как это реализовать. у меня обычный инпут с плейсхолдером, в макете при наведении плейсхолдер должен измениться на слово текст. вид плейсхолдера ниже в форме есть по стилизации

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var input = document.querySelector('input');
var placeholder = input.placeholder;

input.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
  input.placeholder = 'новый текст'
})

input.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
  input.placeholder = placeholder;
})
```

```css
input {
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

input:hover::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  border-bottom: 2px solid blue;
  font-weight: bold;
}

input:hover::-moz-placeholder {
  border-bottom: 2px solid blue;
  font-weight: bold;
}

input:hover:-moz-placeholder {
  border-bottom: 2px solid blue;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<input type='text' placeholder='text'>
```

Comment: я знаю как стилизовать плейсхолдер, мне нужно изменить его содержание при наведении

Comment: @Victoria Pisareva, так?

Comment: как? не вижу ничего

Comment: В смысле? Нажмите "выполнить код". Текст меняется и стилизуется

Comment: а как его сделать кроссбраузерным? у меня такое только в хроме срабатывает

Comment: @Victoria Pisareva, вы про стиль?

Comment: да, про hover. я пробовала префиксы, но не срабатывают

Comment: @Victoria Pisareva, я изменил ответ. Попробуйте ещё раз

Comment: уже лучше, но, например, цвет текста не изменяется

Comment: но уже намного лучше

Comment: Вы какой браузер используете?

Comment: у меня хром и мозила

Comment: вв хроме изначально все в порядке было, а в мозиле после изменений что то подправилось, но некоторые стили все еще хромают

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95550/discussion-between---and-victoria-pisareva).

Answer (score 0):

На основе псевдоэлемента [placeholder](https://webref.ru/css/placeholder)

```css
input::placeholder {opacity: 0;}
input:-ms-input-placeholder {opacity: 0;}
input::-ms-input-placeholder {opacity: 0;}
input::-webkit-input-placeholder {opacity: 0;}
input:-moz-placeholder {opacity: 0;}
input::-moz-placeholder {opacity: 0;}

input:hover::placeholder {opacity: 1;}
input:hover:-ms-input-placeholder {opacity: 1;}
input:hover::-ms-input-placeholder {opacity: 1;}
input:hover::-webkit-input-placeholder {opacity: 1;}
input:hover:-moz-placeholder {opacity: 1;}
input:hover::-moz-placeholder {opacity: 1;}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Текст">
```